# Jenkinsfile task getting faild [Unsupported class file major version 57]

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

### Background:

I got this error earlier [**Unsupported class file major version 57**]

This error means that my version of Java is incompatible with the one with which Gradle was compiled.

My Gradle version was **Gradle 6.0.1** and JDK version was **openjdk 13.0.2**.

So i downgrade JDK to **JDK 11** and issue was resolved.

I was able to run task "***./gradlew spotbugsMain***" in terminal. As well as in Jenkins using WebUI in a shell command. This jobs works fine and success in return.

### Now where the problem is:

I now have to run the jobs using Jenkinsfile instead of a shell command in a Jenkins Project.

So i setup a Jenkins Pipeline for this.

Added my Jenkinsfile and ran the jobs using Jenkins pipeline project.

All my jobs are working fine but "./gradlew spotbugsMain" resulting the same error as earlier [Unsupported class file major version 57]

I checked my Jenkins Project which i am using as shell command to run spotbugs task. it was working fine but Jenkinsfile in Pipeline project is giving error.

I have also added the JDK in Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > JDK > JDK Installations as

[image]

"./gradlew spotbugsMain" working fine in my terminal. Also working fine using Jenkins Project in Jenkins Web UI Where i ran the job as shell command. But not working under a pipeline project which is using Jenkinsfile to run jobs.

### My Jenkinsfile is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Spotbugs') {
            steps {
                sh "./gradlew spotbugsMain"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

### Error:

> Task :app:spotbugsMain FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:spotbugsMain'.
>
> Unsupported class file major version 57

Any help in this problem is appreciated in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update the script to this :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        jdk 'JDK 1.7'
    } 
    stages {
        stage('Spotbugs') {
            steps {
                sh "./gradlew spotbugsMain"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @SajidZeb Is this helpful ?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks you so much Anish. Accepting your answer as solution. Thanks again